# DBT: How to fix Database Error Expecting Value?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, dbt

I was running into troubles today while running Airflow and [airflow-dbt-python](https://github.com/tomasfarias/airflow-dbt-python). I tried to debug a bit using the logs and the error shown in the logs was this one:

```
[2022-12-27, 13:53:53 CET] {functions.py:226} ERROR - [0m12:53:53.642186 [error] [MainThread]: Encountered an error:
Database Error
  Expecting value: line 2 column 5 (char 5)
```

Quite a weird one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly check your credentials file that allows DBT to run queries on your DB (in our case we run DBT with BigQuery), in our case the credentials file was empty. We even tried to run DBT directly in the worker instead of running it through airflow, giving as a result exactly the same error. Unfortunately this error is not really explicit.